# How can I compile C files into an executable (.exe) file?

Tags: c, makefile, executable, exe

I am unsure about compiling C files into executables by using Cygwin under Windows 7.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

I've read some tutorials but still don't get it.  I understand that I need a Makefile, but what shall I write into it to have an executable file after the compilation process?

Comment: Make is one possible compilation tool. Kinda old and a bit unwieldy. For starters, you might be better off with a more modern builder like SCons or perhaps a build system embedded in your IDE (like Eclipse's managed build).

Comment: You don't necessarily need a makefile. But you *do* need a C compiler. Do you have one?

Comment: doesn't `gcc <c-filename>` work for you? It should produce an `a.out` executable file (by default). Of course you can change that as well by using command-line switches

Comment: Here's the first hit on google: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: Thanks for the fast replys! How can i compile the files using mingw-i686-cc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to compile c-files. Makefiles are just one possibility. But as you proposed it... Here are two tutorials for Makefiles:

1. http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html
2. http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/ (Content from 2012 accessable via [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120817090250/http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/))

But note, that you will also need a compiler (installed under cygwin).

Another possibility is to use Dev-C++, a IDE (Integrated Developement Environment) for C++. Once installed you can create a project and add your source code, and just compile the project. It also contains a c++ compiler (also supports C), which is named mingw. The makefile needed is automatically generated. So that's simpler for beginners.

You can download Dev-Cpp here: http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html

Note: As you spoke about cygwin I assume you use Windows. Dev++ works only under windows, and you wont need cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

For the beginning I would say it is enough to Install MinGW. If you have installed it you find in the bin folder a gcc.exe which is the Compiler. Either set the PATH Variable to the bin folder or go directly to this folder.
In terminal use:

```
  gcc your_C_file.c
```

The output will be an exe.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the fast reply! I'm totally new to C programming using a makefile.. Do you know how to compile c-files into .exe using mingw-i686-gcc? Are there different rules? If i search for mingw-i686-gcc, google says nothing -.-

Answer (score 1):

Q: How can i compile c-files into an executable (.exe) file?

A: Get and use a C compiler.

GCC/Cygwin is one possibility.  MS Visual Studio is another: you can download the free "MSVS Express" here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express.

*How* you interact with the compiler is another question.

You can certainly use a command line.

You can use a command line with or without "Make": you can let "Makefiles" do the "heavy lifting" for you, you can use .bat files, or you can type everything by hand.

Using a graphical IDE is another possibility.  "Eclipse" and "MS Visual Studio" are two popular alternatives for Windows.

Answer (score -4):

Even easier solution is A86 Assembler. Its old school but works perfectly, in the right hands ;)