# Write Cordova console.log to file

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Does anyone knows if it is possible the `console.log` to write to a file or something similar?

I have already log for my application but it is only written on the console. For purposes of remote `debugging` I need the existing log to be written to a file too.

I thought of creating a File and write my log inside that file but that will make me duplicate the existing log code. So it could be better if it is possible to redirect where the console.log writes.

My application uses `Ionic`, `Cordova` and is `hybrid for iOS` and android using crosswalk browser plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the plugin [cordova-plugin-logtofile](https://github.com/andischerer/cordova-plugin-logtofile)  that suits your requirement. But unfortunately it works only in Android. 
Since you are using ionic framework, have a look at this too - [FileLogger](https://github.com/pbakondy/filelogger)

Comment: I want to use cordova-plugin-logtofile as I'm using react, but I'm not able to use it. 
Can anyone help me

Comment: I tried logtofile but When I tried with cordova install I'm getting compilation issues and when I tried with npm install I'm getting class not found in 

window.logToFile.setLogfilePath(logPath, function () {
console.log("Logger Logpath set Successfully")
}, function (err) {
console.log("Logger Logpath not set", err)
});

Comment: @Sreenath you gotta pin point what exactly is the error you are facing with trace

Comment: Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
46 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: @Sreenath you may have to debug this by deploying app in device to figure out the complete error trace

Comment: I'm not even able to build it to deploy.

Comment: https://github.com/pbakondy/filelogger this is not working in ionic 4 if you could update your answer it would be great @Gandhi

Answer (score 1):

You need to add plugin console plugin.

To add:

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a logging service to wrap the console.log and the cordova file plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/ (content from 2019 via [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190404233621/http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)).

When you start the app, open a file for writing, then simply use the service to log to the console and the file.

So instead of console.log you use LoggingService.log().

Comment: Well, what's a better way to remove answers that are not helpful anymore (since the link is not working)? As far as I understand, this ensures to keep the topics up to date. If you would update the link (e.g. using a wayback-machine) and the solutions works, I'd also upvote afterwards.

Comment: You honestly think that the substantial amount of posts we make - to help the community, are checked by authors every day and updated to reflect projects that were relevant 4+ years ago - and now deprecated. The answer was correct and relevant at a point in time. Don't be entitled: update the link, make a comment, and move on.

Comment: As en example: your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956743/62282)t from **2012** has a broken link - should we all downvote it? Let's be reasonable and respectful.

Comment: I already got your point. This wasn't meant with disrespect. And yes, probably we should downvote my post, if the link is essential... and re-upvote, if the link gets fixed. I don't make an exception for myself here. However, I should have given you some time to react before downvoting. Sorry for this...

Comment: NP, we are a community and we all need to remember there is no self-benefit in posting and helping others - it's really just to try help your peers. All the best