# cordova file logging framework

Tags: javascript, cordova, logging, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a cordova application, and we need a logging framework. Our requirements are as follows:

1. Logging to a file - we find the javascript console to be too transient
2. different levels of logging as in log4j etc - fine-grained control over what gets logged in production vs development
3. Config file driven - we need to be able to change the log level by dropping in a new config file instead of in code
4. Create a new file each day and only use it until a certain file size, then rotate
5. Not require Angular/Ionic

So far, the closest we have found that fits these needs is https://github.com/andischerer/cordova-plugin-logtofile, but this does not work - there are compilation errors in the java code that we cannot fix.

Are there any such frameworks out there that meet all of these needs?

Comment: will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546615/write-cordova-console-log-to-file ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we're not using Ionic and the logging framework mentioned is the one we had problems with.

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: the compiler cannot find any of the 3rd party libraries the plugin uses. Thinks they're not in the project. But they're included in the build.gradle file, so how can that be?

Comment: Guess there could be some problem with your build. It should pickup all required dependencies on build

Comment: @sophieBrown did you find any solution to this. Please help me

Comment: @SophieBrown I'm getting this issue while compiling